# Como criar uma lista suspensa em html?

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da para criar algo parecido com isso com html?
Ou o que é melhor usar para criar?

Comment: A sua dificuldade é criar uma combobox com HTML?

Comment: na verdade eu não sabia desse comando.

Comment: eu queria criar algo parecido com aquilo da img, e procurei mas não tniha achado nada sobre no google .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está procurando pela tag [select](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp). um dos nomes deste elemento é dropdown.

```html
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: opa mano o cara me passou o combobox também qual você aconselha nesse caso?

Comment: Combo box, caixa de combinação, lista suspensa, dropdown. todos são a mesma coisa. A implementação em HTML é o `<select>`

Comment: Dropdown é uma definição de UI Design... não é um alias ou "outro nome" para a tag `<select>` e não faz parte da especificação HTML. Eu recomendaria remover o trecho que faz alusão a "outro nome"

Comment: Sim, mas todos os termos representam o mesmo elemento para o usuário do sistema. Não disse que é um alias, mas que a implementação em HTML deste elemento é via select.

Comment: muito obrigado mano, Você poderia me tirar só mais uma duvida? tipo eu quero fazer duas caixas delas lado a lado uma por exemplo: pode ser pizza 1 e a outra seria refrigerante ( apenas um exp) e então selecionando uma opition de cada gerar um botão com o valor, eu precisaria de php ou da pra fazer só com html?

Comment: Recomendo que leia algum tutorial sobre formulários em HTML. Você cria um formulário e dentro dele vários elementos, um deles é chamado submit. O submit, envia o valor de todos os elementos dentro do formulário.

Answer (score -2):

....você pode, também, disponibilizar o elemento html "select" para que o usuário faça múltiplas seleções de "options", declarando-o da seguinte forma: 
  . Repare o atributo "**multiple**".

...dessa forma, selecionar, de mais de 1 "option", o usuário deve manter pressionada  a tecla "Ctrl" enquanto faz as seleções de mais de 1 "option".

Porém, aconselho, no caso do usuário ter de selecionar múltiplos "options", o uso do elemento html do tipo "checkbox", haja visto que esse elemento não tem restrição quanto ao Sistema Operacional, enquanto que o Select com atributo múltiplo no MAC a tecla que deve manter pressionada enquanto faz a seleção com o mouse não é a mesma tecla CTRL usada no Windows ou LINUX. No Linux é também usada a tecla CTRL, mas no MAC não é.

Obrigado.